# Create menu items automatically when creating a page in WordPress. How to?

Tags: wordpress, menu

For Wordpress, when creating a page, a menu entry will be added to top level menu automatically. I have disabled this feature because it is not what I what.

What I want is, like Drupal, when creating a page, I can have a dropdown select to select which menu to add this page to and to which parent.

Which plugin can do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it yourself. What you need to do is:

1. Use `add_meta_box` to add a meta box to your post editor. In that meta box, build a list of available menus using results from `get_registered_nav_menus()` function.
2. Add a hook to `save_post` action, which will create a menu item.
3. Create a menu item by calling `wp_save_nav_menu_items($menu_id, $item_data)`

It is not a piece of cake, but you can do it in a couple of hours.

Comment: Ｔｈａｎｋｓ　ｆｏｒ　ｙｏｕｒ　ｈｅｌｐ．　Ｕｎｆｏｒｔｕｎａｔｅｌｙ, Ｉ　ａｍ　ｕｎａｂｌｅ　ｔｏ　ｄｏ　ｔｈａｔ　ｓｉｎｃｅ　Ｉ　ｄｏ　ｎｏｔ　ｈａｖｅ　ｓｈｅｌｌ　ａｃｃｅｓｓ．　Ｉ　ｃａｎ　ｏｎｌｙ　ｃｕｓｔｏｍｉｚｅ　ｔｈｒｏｕｇｈ　ｗｅｂ　ｉｎｔｅｒｆａｃｅ　（ｉｅ：　custom css, etc). Is there a plugin that can do that? I can ask our IT dept to install the plugin, if they are okay with. :)

Comment: I bet there are no plugins to do that. If you don't have FTP/shell access, you can use WordPress builtin theme editor at admin - appearance - edit

Comment: Hi Karevn. Thank you. Could you please give more hints on how to do that? I am new to Wordpress from Drupal.

Comment: I can't explain in short. You need to read about wordpress actions, filters, in WordPress Codex, and then add some specific hooks. The best thing I am using for documentation is WP code usually - codex sucks when it comes to small particularities in using API.